# Getting "OSError: Unable to run gpg () - it may not be available." error with python-gnupg

Tags: python, gnupg

I am trying to make a simple tool that decrypts a GPG message, but I keep getting an error decrypting the message, I dont know where the issue is coming from.

Here is the code:

```
import gnupg
import os

message = '''-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2
jA0ECQMCVady3RUyJw3X0kcBF+zdkfZOMhISoYBRwR3uk3vNv+TEg+rJnp4/yYIS
pEoI2S82cDiCNBIVAYWB8WKPtH2R2YSussKhpSJ4mFgqyOA01uwroA==
=KvJQ
-----END PGP MESSAGE----- 
'''

passphrase = 'topsecret'

gpg = gnupg.GPG(os.popen("which gpg").read().strip())

decrypted_data = str(gnupg.decrypt(message, passphrase=passphrase))

print(decrypted_data)
```

Here is the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(os.popen("which gpg").read().strip())
  File "/Users/***/PycharmProjects/untitled8/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnupg.py", line 849, in __init__
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: Unable to run gpg () - it may not be available.
```

Answer (score 3):

The `python-gnupg` packages requires you to have a working installation of the `gpg` executable.

From the [Deployment Requirements](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/#deployment-requirements) docs:

> Apart from a recent-enough version of Python, in order to use this
>   module you need to have access to a compatible version of the GnuPG
>   executable. The system has been tested with GnuPG v1.4.9 on Windows
>   and Ubuntu. On a Linux platform, this will typically be installed via
>   your distribution’s package manager (e.g. `apt-get` on Debian/Ubuntu).
>   Windows binaries are available [here](ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/) – use one of the
>   `gnupg-w32cli-1.4.x.exe` installers for the simplest deployment options.

The error you got was pretty clear:

> OSError: Unable to run gpg () - it may not be available.

It's from this part:

```
os.popen("which gpg").read().strip()
```

Try running `which gpg` from a terminal/console. If you don't have `gpg` installed, `which gpg` will evaluate to an empty string `''`, and then that entire line will evaluate to an empty `''` string. It would effectively be same as

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG('')
```

which will then raise the sameerror that it can't find the `gpg` executable.

So, basically, you'll need to install `gpg` first.

If you already have `gpg` installed and for some reason `which gpg` just can't find it, you could also pass a [`gpgbinary` parameter](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/#getting-started):

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gpgbinary="/usr/local/bin/gpg")
```

Comment: Thanks!  One small change I needed was to change 'gpg' to 'gpg2'.
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gpgbinary="/usr/local/bin/gpg2")

Answer (score 0):

I spent multiple hours trying to find a solution to this issue because the different solutions proposed were not working.

I found two solutions:

**First, you need to find the gpg file on your computer, for that you have multiple options**

- You can open a command-line and type `gpg --version`, you will see something like that (If you don't see it, you need to download GnuPG from the official website):

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.8
libgcrypt 1.10.1
Copyright (C) 2021 g10 Code GmbH
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
AEAD: EAX, OCB
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

- Where `Home` is the folder we are looking for. Go to that path and see if you find the `gpg`, if yes that is the path.
- If you didn't find the `gpg` file, you can look in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\gnupg\bin`, that's where I did find it.

**Once you have found the path you have to add that path to the system environment variables**

- Depending on which system you are the process is different. You can see other discussion explaining the process.
- Once this is done, your program should be working

**If not, you can try**

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gpgbinary="C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\gnupg\\bin\\gpg")
```

Replace the path with the one you found